# Creating EAN-13 Barcodes with C#

Tags: c#, barcode

When I try to print the barcode generated in that program my device reader does not recognize it. Why? (I had used other devices also)

I'm using this [rainman_63 project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10162/Creating-EAN-Barcodes-with-C%20by%20rainman_63)

Images:

[image]

[image]

The barcode generated by rainman_63's project doesn't work, but the barcode generated by a internet page (second image) are working. Maybe has anyone already study rainman_63's project and can point the possible error? Thank you.

Comment: I just tested both images with the scanner I have on my desk. They both scan just fine and both return `7893456756767`. I would double check your scanner or possibly try to widen your bars. Your scanner might not be able to read the super thin bars.

Comment: Right, probably can be the width of bar. I will try to fix it. Thanks for now.